# Negate SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem: I have to fetch **all driver's name that didn't scheduled in specified schedule**. I can fetch all driver's name scheduled in specified schedule using the following query but I can't negate it. Please give me direction on how to do it. Thanks.

```
select drivername from driver inner join driverschedule
on driver.driverid = driverschedule.driverid
where scheduleid = 1
```

[image: simple ERD]

Comment: I think you want a cross join

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a LEFT OUTER JOIN and checking for no matching row (ie, the r/h table columns are null):-

```
SELECT drivername 
FROM driver 
LEFT OUTER JOIN driverschedule
ON driver.driverid = driverschedule.driverid
AND scheduleid = 1
WHERE driverschedule.driverid IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Using EXISTS <strike>should perform better than a left join</strike> also works, but is apparently slower than a LEFT JOIN with an IS NULL (see comments).

```
select drivername 
from driver
where not exists ( select 1
                   from driverschedule
                   where driver.driverid = driverschedule.driverid
                   and   driverschedule.scheduleid = 1 )
```

Comment: Performance may not be what you think (although I doubt the query time is going to be long enough to warrant a concern)  See http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/ as a counter example

Comment: @AgRizzo Intresesting. They are optimized in the same way, but MySql does a worse job for EXISTS.